dataGovernanceTags Error in Bigquery Uploading
I am trying to manually upload a csv file to Bigquery. I am doing an "append to table" upload and I am encountering this error:
Invalid value at 'job.configuration.load.schema.fields[0]' (Map), Cannot bind a list to map for field 'dataGovernanceTags'.
Looking at the error, this suggests a schema problem. However, I have checked the existing table, the schema, and the contents of the new file, they are all matching in fields. I have been running this process weekly and I have only encountered this error just this once. I tried creating a new table using the same file and it worked. Therefore, only the append to table has this problem.
Are there updates in BigQuery that may have caused this? Is there another step needed to successfully append to a BQ table? Thank you!

This is an issue with big query product itself and resolved now.can you please verify now.
